# Carbon::now() - only month

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I couldn't find anywhere in [documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) how to show current year or month with Carbon?

when i write this:

`Carbon\Carbon::now('m');`

it gives me the whole time stamp, but I just need the month

like

```
date('m');
```

but it must be Carbon!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried this? $date = Carbon\Carbon::now(); $date->month; ? See the [docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters).

Comment: this works `Carbon::now()->month`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
$now = Carbon::now();
echo $now->year;
echo $now->month;
echo $now->weekOfYear;
```

Update:

even this works since Laravel 5.5^

```
echo now()->month
```

Comment: and can i get the M version with letters for example M = Nov

Answer (score 25):

I think you've already worked this out in a comment, but just for clarity: Carbon extends [PHP's native `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), so you can use any of the methods available on that, like [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
Carbon::now()->format('M');
```

(where `M` is the modifier for *A short textual representation of a month, three letters*)

Answer (score 18):

You can use these both ways to get the current month

```
Carbon::now()->month;
```

or

```
Carbon::now()->format('m');
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use this in your any blade file for print year:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->year }}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to get the current month and got to this question, to get the current month:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$monthStart = $now->startOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 2):

w/ Carbon + Laravel:

```
now()->format('M')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$today= Carbon::now();

echo $today->year;
echo $today->month;
echo $today->day;
echo $today->hour;
echo $today->minute;
echo $today->second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant call it statically
use

$now = Carbon::now();

echo $now->month

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8

```
return date('m');
```

or

```
return now()->format('m');
```